# Upgrading to Cypress 12 made it so that only the first test passes now

Tags: cypress

I upgraded to Cypress 12 today. Since upgrading, only the first test is passing and all following tests are failing.

For example, I have an HTML file with a nav element inside of a header element. And I have the following tests:

```
it('Contains header Element', () => {
    cy.get('header');
})

it('Contains nav element in header Element', () => {
    cy.get('header nav');
})
```

Before upgrading, both tests would have passed. Since upgrading, only the first test passes. This is consistent across all files I have tested.

What is different between older versions of Cypress and version 12 that would cause this?

The beginning of my .cy.js (which was a .spec file before the upgrade) is as follows:

```
const urls = require('../fixtures/students.json');
let files = ["index", "discover", "join", "directory", "contact"];

describe(`Check assignments`, () => {
urls.forEach(url => {
    describe(`Current student: ${url}`, () => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            describe(`Current file: ${file}.html`, () => {
                before(() => {
                    base_url = `https://[redacted]/`;
                    current_url = `${base_url}${file}.html`;
                    cy.visit(current_url);
                })

                it('Contains header Element', () => {
                    cy.get('header');
                })

                it('Contains nav element in header Element', () => {
                    cy.get('header nav');
                })
```

Comment: It could be test isolation, but would need more details to be sure. How are you navigating to the website?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the beginning of my test file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be the [test isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) introduced in Cypress 12.

The issue is `before()` performs your `cy.visit()`, but test isolation means that the page is cleared (navigated to a neutral page) between tests.

If you change it to `beforeEach()` you should be up and running again.